# PHP mkdir failing

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to upload a file so here's my html:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here's my php:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    session_start();
    $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx");
    $extension = pathinfo( $_FILES["upload"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (($_FILES["upload"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

            $dir_exists = is_dir("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/");
            $file_exists = file_exists("Proposals/".$_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
            $folderName=$_SESSION["FirstName"];
            $baseDir = "Proposals" ;
            //var_dump($_FILES);
            //die();
            // Create directory if it does not exist
            if (! $dir_exists) {
                if(!is_dir($baseDir))
                    mkdir($baseDir);
                mkdir($baseDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_SESSION["FirstName"]);
            } 

            if ($file_exists) {
                echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
                "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }

?>
```

The file outputted:

```
Type: application/msword
Size: 124.9296875 Kb
Temp file: /tmp/phpUWDc3s
```

The var_dump outputted this on a test file:

```
array(1) { ["upload"]=> array(5) { 
["name"]=> string(18) "Test.doc" 
["type"]=> string(18) "application/msword" 
["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpUWDc3s" 
["error"]=> int(0) 
["size"]=> int(127928) } }
```

And the warnings/errors it gives me are:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 6 Upload: Test.doc
```

WITHOUT the mkdir code it gives me:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(Proposals/Test.doc): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 40 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpQmgxdO' to 'Proposals/Test.doc' in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 40 Stored in: Proposals/Test.doc
```

For some reason with or without the mkdir, no file is being put in the Proposals paper even if it's the right file type. Is this just a permission issue with the server or is there something I have to add/change to make this all work?

Comment: try giving `file_put_contents('Proposals/Test.txt', 'test');` at the top of the script and see if the file is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. The first Error

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 6 Upload: Test.doc

Change

```
  $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["upload"]["name"]));
```

To

```
  $extension = path_info( $_FILES["upload"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

B. The second error

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(Proposals/Test.doc): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 40 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpQmgxdO' to 'Proposals/Test.doc' in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 40 Stored in: Proposals/Test.doc

Use something like this with full path `/disks/vhosts/***/***/`

```
$baseDir = __DIR__ ; // or /disks/vhosts/***/***/ has applicable 
if (! $dir_exists) {
    if (is_writable("$baseDir/Proposals/")) {
        mkdir("$baseDir/Proposals/" . $_SESSION["FirstName"]);
    } else {
        trigger_error("Proposals/ is not writeable");
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, that didn't work. it still didn't create a directory. Now the warnings are: `Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 31 Warning: move_uploaded_file(Proposals/***/Test.doc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 38 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php9zFSIM' to 'Proposals/***/Test.doc' in /disks/vhosts/***/***/upload_file.php on line 38 Stored in: Proposals/***/Test.doc`

Comment: so whereever i have "Proposals/" change it to "/disks/vhosts/***/***/Proposals"?

Comment: have somthing like `$baseDir = "/disks/vhosts/name/name/Proposals"` or you can just use `__DIR__` to get full path to current directory

Comment: yah it says directory is not writeable so I guess it's a permission issue. Will have to talk to the it head to get it resolved i guess

Comment: @Charlie Yabben  i hope i was able to help .. let me know if you still have issues

Answer (score 1):

You currently have this code...

```
if(!$dir_exists) {
    mkdir("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"]);
} elseif ($file_exists) {
    echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
    "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
}
```

Which will ONLY `move_uploaded_file` if the directory you're looking for exists. Move that line below your `if` statement, and it should then create the directory if needed, then upload the file.

Comment: Yah i just noticed that logical error as well. It's fixed now but still doesn't create dir. Updated code in post.

Comment: I just tested the code, and it worked fine for me. Make sure that php user (dependant upon OS) has the ability to write in this directory. If you are unsure about who the php user is, do `echo exec('whoami');`. That will echo out the php user within your OS. I'm on a mac currently, so mine is `_www`. Which means, that the `_www` user would need read and write access in the directory you're hosting these scripts.